# Is Separator First Formating (SFF) with SQL Code Formating easier to read/maintain?

Tags: sql, formatting

Do you place separators (commas, and, or operators) at the front of the line?

```
Select Field1
    , Field2
  --, Field3
From [some_table] as ST
Inner Join [other_table] as OT
   ON ST.PKID = OT.FKID
Where [this] = [that]
   and [one_other] > 53;
```

I think the best feature is to help expose important operators (AND/OR). As a secondary advantage it seems easier to comment out.

Not sure where I picked it up initially, but Andrew Novick mentions it in "Transact-SQL User-Defined Function" (Heard him speak; got the book for free and highly recommend.)

Comment: I normally indent, but missed it here. In Microsoft SQL Management Studio, I have my Tab set to 4 spaces. Stackoverflow doesn't like the tab key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At my workplace (small consultancy company with about 10 developers, specialising in Oracle) that is what our convention is, as so:

```
SELECT
  p.id pd_id
, p.var_no
, p.status
, o.name operator
, o.r_id
, o.r_type
, o.start_datetime
, o.end_datetime
--, p.id rd_id
--, p.s_control
, p.xml_data last_d_res_xml
FROM schema_a.table_x p
JOIN schema_b.table_y o ON p.id = o.pd_id
WHERE p.some_id = 11
ORDER BY pd_id DESC, end_datetime DESC NULLS FIRST
```

We find it is quite clear and allows easy commenting of columns when debugging. It took a while to get used to but I prefer this style now - and it is consistently used by our whole team.

Answer (score 4):

It's easier to comment out, but I'd rather go for readability - Using a column layout like the one below is a bit awkward while the code is changing a lot, but it's very comfortable to get an overview:

```
select foo.bar,
       baz.ban,
       foobar.bazban
  from foomatic  foo
  join bartastic bar  on bar.id  = foo.id
  join anemone   anem on anem.id = bar.id
 where foo.bar <> 1 and
       baz.ban =  'foo' and
       (
         anem.bear in ('a', 'b') or
         anem.zoo  is null
       )
;
```

Comment: You would use this column layout and still place separators first.

Comment: When separators are in front (commas in particular), they form their own column -- and that makes it easy to avoid missing comma problems, missing ON clause problems, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I personally don't find this easier to read, but that is only because I am not used to it.  The important thing to remember is that *consistency is the key* in these matters.  Make sure that whatever style you choose is the one and only style used for the entire project.

Answer (score 2):

"Easier to comment out" - unless you want to comment out the first item.

It doesn't matter if your separators are at the start or the end of the line - there will always be an edge case where you can't apply the "easily comment out" criterion.

And if you're looking at the operator level (AND/OR), then an easily commented out line may:

- Change the meaning of the query
- Result in a syntax error

In general, for the where clauses, if it's not all ANDs, then I tend to nest:

```
WHERE
    ColumnA = 1 AND
    ColumnB = 2 AND
    (
        ColumnC = 3 OR
        ColumnD = 4
    )
```

This helps you to spot the edge cases (mentioned above) where you'll need to comment an operator or add a "1=1" condition in front of the comment block.

Comment: Good point on the first item. I would hope commenting out the line would change the meaning. Your example is more likely to create a syntax error if one of the lines were commented out.

Comment: The point is, you can never avoid these oddities - and usually you'll create syntax errors (thankfully). But if you have a lot of unbracketed uses of ANDs and ORs (relying on syntax rules), and you comment out a line, you can suddenly end up with a far more restrictive, or far more lax, WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten sloppy with this, but that is my preferred method of writing things out - especially when I am debugging a new script.

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard at my most recent engagement. Took a little while to get used to, now anything else looks strange to me :)

```
SELECT e.emp_id
      ,e.emp_name
      ,d.dept_name
FROM   emp   e
      ,dept  d
WHERE  e.dept_id        = d.dept_id
AND    d.is_active      = 'Y'
AND    e.current_status = 'ACTIVE'
AND    (e.class IN ('x','y','z')
        OR e.class_na = 'Y')
ORDER BY e.emp_name
        ,d.dept_name;
```

We found having everything lined up in columns made queries more easily read, especially when you've got a number of SQL statements in PL/SQL. The SQL stood out neatly from the surrounding procedural code.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer SELECT clause separation.

This highlights the important parts of a query. Separator front or end only matters now in the SELECT list

I find all above examples difficult to read.

```
Select
    Field1
    , Field2
    --, Field3
From
    [some_table] as ST
    Inner Join
    [other_table] as OT ON ST.PKID = OT.FKID
Where
    [this] = [that]
    and
    [one_other] > 53;


Select
    Field1,
    Field2 --,
    --Field3
From
    [some_table] as ST
    Inner Join
    [other_table] as OT ON ST.PKID = OT.FKID
Where
    [this] = [that]
    AND
    [one_other] > 53;
```